# Import vim in python gives back errors

Tags: python, vim

I read some articles about Vimscripting with python. I felt very interested. So I tried to figure out how to do vimscripting with python.
But when I tried to import vim, it showed that the module vim wasn't installed. So I searched
on the web, but still haven't find the module to install.
I also tried pip to search automatically, still failed.
Does anyone know where to find the module vim?

I am using fedora 17, and I have installed vim 7.3 and python 2.7.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the error message:

```
>>> import vim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vim
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you need to import it, just make sure your vim is compiled with python support. Check this using **vim --version | grep +python**. Further, it seems that the vim module is imported automatically when in vim, rendering your import line unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

it do not work but this will work

```
:python from vim import *
:python command('echo "Hello World!"')
```

if you put `vim.command(..`

You get

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'vim' is not defined
```

Comment: No matter what you should never import "*" because you never know which names from the package will be overriden

Answer (score 1):

Compile VI with python as described by hd1.  You can find the documentation here:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html

**If you want to test**

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Note that I installed all in local, this is why I use $HOME in PYTHONPATH

Run vi then, type

```
:python from vim import *
:python vim.command('echo "Hello World!"')
```

you should see "Hello World!" below.